# Why is the current user having no data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve the current user session then send the data to the view but in the view there is nothing showing i event check the database and there is an active session with all the info. I tried logging the user out and started afresh. Here is my code.

Login works well

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body || req.body.length === 0) {
        console.log('request body not found');
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
    success: function (user) {

        res.redirect('/');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    },
    error: function (user, error) {

    }
});
});
```

Retrieve current user in the index.js

```
var username;
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser){
        currentUser.fetch().then(function (fetchedUser) {
            this.username = fetchedUser.getUsername();
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: this.username});
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i try to display the username `h1=user` there is nothing shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow functions for access to outer context(`this`):

```
currentUser.fetch().then(fetchedUser => {
  this.username = fetchedUser.getUsername();
}, error => console.error(error));
```

But, it can't to help you, because you tried to render **before** user was fetched. You need to wait while fetch finished.

```
if (currentUser) {
  currentUser.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: fetchedUser.getUsername()});
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    // may be render something with err.message here
  });
} else {
  // render without user
  res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: null});
}
```

Comment: i tried render before user was fetched no change and the above code produces a 500 error.

Comment: my last edit was after you write comment, can you confirm you use actual answer code? Read the comment in the `catch` section. Server must response here something.

Comment: Also, my answer is not just correct code. It's more pointing to your mistakes.

Comment: Still the same and also the arrows are showing errors in the IDE(Webstorm 2016). These are the code changes. `router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (currentUser) {
        currentUser.fetch().then(fetchedUser => {
            res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: fetchedUser.getUsername()});
    }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        // may be render something with err.message here
    });
    } else {
        // render without user
        res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: "User not available"});
    }
});
` Node Version 5.6

Comment: I don't know what node version are you use. Updated code to usual functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are getting value for `this.username`

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var that = this;
    if (currentUser){
        currentUser.fetch().then(function (fetchedUser) {
            that.username = fetchedUser.getUsername();
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: that.username});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Store a reference of `this` and then try to display it using `res.render`

Comment: i don't understand check the new code edit if its what you meant.